# Raspberry Pi + Gertduino

Tags: arduino, gertboard

I realize this might not be a typical RPi question.

However, I have a RPi with a Gertduino plugged into the GPIO headers.

I can use the wrapper program_328 for avrdude to upload a precompiled blink.hex file. OR use the arduino program (with X11 forwarded to my local machine) and upload the sketch with the "Upload sketch with programmer"

However, how can I write raw "sketch"/C code, and then compile it to the proper hex file and use the wrapper program_328 to upload the hex code to the Gertduino without using the arduino program?

Comment: you can probably use avr dude (which is what the arduino program does in the background) to upload a compiled file. As for compiling you can use avr studio and may even be able to use the cloud ide https://codebender.cc/

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally familiar with the `Gertduino`, but use a `Gertboard`. Both are programmed using the `ICSP` interface. `program_328` is a script used to upload to this, `Avrdude` for `Gertboard` uploads using `avrdude` with appropriate configuration files provided by Gordon Henderson, as described on his site. You should be able to use either `program_328` or `avrdude` to upload HEX files.

If your question is how to compile `c` code to `hex` then you would use the avr compiler `avr-gcc` (located in /usr/bin).